# Copy Cell values from One Sheet to Another on certain criteria with the paste

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to make a macro which will copy all the 200 values from Sheet1 from A1 until A2 , and will paste them in Sheet 2 but the paste operation should paste them differently in 2 columns and in 3 rows space, for example.

```
Sheet1(A1) => Sheet2(A1)
Sheet1(A2) => Sheet2(B1)

Sheet1(A3) => Sheet2(A5)
Sheet1(A4) => Sheet2(B5)    

Sheet1(A5) => Sheet2(A9)
Sheet1(A6) => Sheet2(B9)
```

As you can see the interval is +3 cells.
So far what I made is to copy individual cell, and need any help or suggestions how to make the copy process from above.

```
Sub CopySelection()
  Dim xlSel As Excel.Range
  Set xlSel = Excel.Application.Selection
  For i = 0 To 200
  xlSel.copy Excel.Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
  Next i
End Sub
```

Any Help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Dim Destination_Row As Integer
Destination_Row = 1
For Origin_Row = 1 To 200 Step 2
    Sheet2.Cells(Destination_Row, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(Origin_Row, 1).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(Destination_Row, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(Origin_Row + 1, 1).Value
    Destination_Row = Destination_Row + 4
Next
```

The `Cells` property returns a `Range` for the specified `Row` and `Column`.
Every step of the `For` loop adds 2 to get the value from `Sheet1` and adds 4 to the `Destination_Row` to paste the value on `Sheet2`.

Comment: It works, only issues is that it is not pasting in Sheet2 if I change the properities to past in sheet1 it works but not for sheet2

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, why is it not working?

Comment: the correct Sheet in the file was not specified, now everything is fine, thanks!